# How to label separate lines in the image (image of a text) separately using "bwlabel" in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, text, label

I have recognized and labeled objects in my image that is fully consists of texts. you can see the objects are labeled as red color in the attached image. so, I want to **separate** the objects in the *second line* (or more lines) from the *first line* and give them different colors (each line would has a different colors) but I can't do that. do you have any idea? thanks for all answers.
this is part of my **matlab** code that does the labeling:

```
%% Label connected components
[L, Ne]=bwlabel(imagen);
%% Measure properties of image regions
propied=regionprops(L,'BoundingBox');
hold on
%% Plot Bounding Box
for n=1:size(propied,1)
    rectangle('Position',propied(n).BoundingBox,'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2)
end
```

and this is labeled image that all the objects in different lines have the same label (same color=red).
[image]

Comment: Could you please also upload the original image? Do you know a priori how many lines there are?

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger The original image does not have any red rectangles. We can assume that we have two lines. like attached picture.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following methods should work if the lines are not too curvy.

- Find the centroids of the bounding boxes, or get the centroids from the `regionprops` itself, then cluster their y coordinates using kmeans with k = 2.
  The result is not perfect, but fine. May be you can then fit a curve to the clustered points, with outlier removal (e.g. RANSAC)

[image: cluster]

OR

- Prepare a new image by filling in the bounding boxes.
  [image: filled]
- Prepare a rectangular structuring element whose height is 1 and width is the width of the widest bounding box.
- Perform a morphological closing of the filled image using this structuring element. This will connect the regions horizontally. Now you get a mask separating the two regions.
  [image: closed]

The resulting images were obtained using `opencv` (I'm not posting the code because it's too untidy. Hope the instructions are clear enough).